# Thread function in separate file with pthread and make

Tags: c, gcc, makefile, pthreads

There is a problem with the code below when creating a thread with `pthread_create()` when the thread function passed as an argument, is in a separate file. It works fine when in the same file.

I have `Main.c`, `ThreadFunction.h`, `ThreadFunction.c` and a `makefile`. I am guessing that the problem is with the `makefile` but i just can't figure it out.

**My question:**

Is it because the `ThreadFunction.o` object file is not made with `-pthread`? If that is why, how do you do it? Or is it because of something else?

Here is code that creates my problem:

**Main.c**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include "ThreadFunction.h"

int main(int argc, char * argv[]) 
{
    pthread_t tid;
    int err;
    void *res;
    err = pthread_create(&tid, NULL, &ThreadFunction, "Argument from main");
    err = pthread_join(tid, &res);
    return 0;
}
```

**ThreadFunction.h**

```
static void *ThreadFunction(void *arg);
```

**ThreadFunction.c**

```
#include "ThreadFunction.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pthread.h>

static void *ThreadFunction(void *arg)
{
    pthread_t id = pthread_self();
    printf("From thread: %s\n", (char *)arg);
    printf("Thread ID: %ld\n", id);
}
```

**Makefile**

```
LINK_TARGET = test.exe
OBJS = Main.o ThreadFunction.o
REBUILDABLES = $(OBJS) $(LINK_TARGET)
LIBS = -pthread

clean:
    rm -f $(REBUILDABLES)
    echo Clean done

all: $(LINK_TARGET)
    echo All done

$(LINK_TARGET) : $(OBJS)
    gcc -g -o $@ $^ $(LIBS)

$.o : $.cpp
    gcc -g -o $@ -c $<

Main.o : ThreadFunction.h
ThreadFunction.o : ThreadFunction.h
```

Comment: your `ThreadFunction` is static, which means it is only available at file scope.

Answer (score 3):

static functions are module-local and are not visible to other compilation units. Remove the `static` from its definition and declaration.